# Duplicated value during Controls.Add()

Tags: c#, webforms, controls, duplicates, code-behind

I work with ASP Web form and C#. I use UserControl, so I create controls programmatically in code-behind.

I have a listview and when I select an item, a function populates my controls (label and textbox) for showing details of my selected item. I have a read mode (label) and an edit mode (textbox). I must go through the read mode to access the edit mode.

I have two scenarios :

- when I create a new item, and show its details in stride
- when I edit an item, set new value(s) and show its details in stride

I see that the duplicate value is set when I add the control in my UserControl with using this.Controls.Add(). The problem disapears after the first consultation.

For example, if I set a value for my textbox, it is duplicated in the folowing control. If I set values for the two first textboxes, the first value is duplicated in the second, the second value is duplicated in the third.

I check that no controls has the same id. When I use breakpoint and add watches, I can see that my function is good and that the duplicated value is set during this.Controls.Add().

This is my code :

```
public class GetSetConfig : UserControl, IConfig
{
    #region Composants
    // Composants pour le mode edit
    TextBox tUrl = new TextBox();
    RegularExpressionValidator valUrl = new RegularExpressionValidator();
    TextBox tHttpResp = new TextBox();
    TextBox tCredentials = new TextBox();
    TextBox tExpectedResult = new TextBox();
    TextBox tMaxExecTime = new TextBox();
    CompareValidator valMaxExecTime = new CompareValidator();
    TextBox tMaxDelay = new TextBox();
    CompareValidator valMaxDelay = new CompareValidator();
    TextBox tTimeout = new TextBox();
    CompareValidator valTimeout = new CompareValidator();
    // Composants pour le mode read         
    Label lUrlGetter = new Label();
    Label lHttpRespGetter = new Label();
    Label lCredentialsGetter = new Label();
    Label lExpectedResultGetter = new Label();
    Label lMaxExecTimeGetter = new Label();
    Label lMaxDelayGetter = new Label();
    Label lTimeoutGetter = new Label();
    #endregion

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        #region Edit
        tUrl.ID = "tUrl";
        tHttpResp.ID = "tHttpResp";
        tCredentials.ID = "tCredentials";
        tExpectedResult.ID = "tExpectedResult";
        tMaxExecTime.ID = "tMaxExecTime";
        tMaxDelay.ID = "tMaxDelay";
        tTimeout.ID = "tTimeout";
        #endregion
        #region Validation
        //// Url
        valUrl.ID = "valUrl";
        valUrl.ControlToValidate = tUrl.ID;
        valUrl.ValidationExpression = @"((http:\/\/|https:\/\/)(www.)?(([a-zA-Z0-9-]){2,}\.){1,4}([a-zA-Z]){2,6}(\/([a-zA-Z-_/.0-9#:+?%=&;,]*)?)?)";
        valUrl.ErrorMessage = "Invalid format. Url must begin with http:// or https://.";
        //// Max exec time
        valMaxExecTime.ID = "valMaxExecTime";
        valMaxExecTime.ControlToValidate = tMaxExecTime.ID;
        valMaxExecTime.Type = ValidationDataType.Integer;
        valMaxExecTime.Operator = ValidationCompareOperator.GreaterThanEqual;
        valMaxExecTime.ValueToCompare = 0.ToString();
        valMaxExecTime.ErrorMessage = "Invalid format. Please enter a number greater than or equal to 0.";
        //// Max delay
        valMaxDelay.ID = "valMaxDelay";
        valMaxDelay.ControlToValidate = tMaxDelay.ID;
        valMaxDelay.Type = ValidationDataType.Integer;
        valMaxDelay.Operator = ValidationCompareOperator.GreaterThanEqual;
        valMaxDelay.ValueToCompare = 0.ToString();
        valMaxDelay.ErrorMessage = "Invalid format. Please enter a number greater than or equal to 0.";
        //// Timeout
        valTimeout.ID = "valTimeout";
        valTimeout.ControlToValidate = tTimeout.ID;
        valTimeout.Type = ValidationDataType.Integer;
        valTimeout.Operator = ValidationCompareOperator.GreaterThanEqual;
        valTimeout.ValueToCompare = 0.ToString();
        valTimeout.ErrorMessage = "Invalid format. Please enter a number greater than or equal to 0";
        #endregion
        #region Read
        lUrlGetter.ID = "lUrlGetter";
        lHttpRespGetter.ID = "lHttpRespGetter";
        lCredentialsGetter.ID = "lCredentialsGetter";
        lExpectedResultGetter.ID = "lExpectedResultGetter";
        lMaxExecTimeGetter.ID = "lMaxExecTimeGetter";
        lMaxDelayGetter.ID = "lMaxDelayGetter";
        lTimeoutGetter.ID = "lTimeoutGetter";
        #endregion
        base.OnInit(e);
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        // tester EditMode pour gerer l'affichage : getter ou setter ?
        //
        #region ce qui ne change jamais
        // Controls thate never change
        #endregion
        if (this.EditMode == true)
        {
            #region Mode edit
            // Url interrogee
            this.Controls.Add(tUrl);
            this.Controls.Add(valUrl);
            // Http response
            this.Controls.Add(tHttpResp);
            // Credentials
            this.Controls.Add(tCredentials);
            // Expected result
            this.Controls.Add(tExpectedResult);
            // Max exec time
            this.Controls.Add(tMaxExecTime);
            this.Controls.Add(valMaxExecTime);
            // Max delay
            this.Controls.Add(tMaxDelay);
            this.Controls.Add(valMaxDelay);
            // Timeout
            this.Controls.Add(tTimeout);
            this.Controls.Add(valTimeout);
            #endregion
        }
        else
        {
            #region Mode read
            // Url interrogee
            this.Controls.Add(lUrlGetter);
            // Http response
            this.Controls.Add(lHttpRespGetter);
            // Credentials
            this.Controls.Add(lCredentialsGetter);
            // Expected result
            this.Controls.Add(lExpectedResultGetter); // DUPLICATED VALUE SETS HERE !!
            // Max exec time
            this.Controls.Add(lMaxExecTimeGetter);
            // Max delay
            this.Controls.Add(lMaxDelayGetter);
            // Timeout
            this.Controls.Add(lTimeoutGetter);
            #endregion
        }

        base.CreateChildControls();
    }

    // Save new details after I edit the selected item
    public ISettings SaveSettings()
    {
        var settings = new Settings();
        settings.Url = tUrl.Text;
        settings.HttpResponse = tHttpResp.Text;
        settings.Credentials = tCredentials.Text;
        settings.ExpectedResult = tExpectedResult.Text;
        settings.MaxExecTime = tMaxExecTime.Text;
        settings.MaxDelay = tMaxDelay.Text;
        settings.Timeout = tTimeout.Text;
        return settings;
    }

    // Populate my controls with details of my selected item
    public void LoadSettings(ISettings settings)
    {
        Settings getSettings = new Settings();
        getSettings = (Settings)settings;
        lUrlGetter.Text = tUrl.Text = getSettings.Url;
        lHttpRespGetter.Text = tHttpResp.Text = getSettings.HttpResponse;
        lCredentialsGetter.Text = tCredentials.Text = getSettings.Credentials;
        lExpectedResultGetter.Text = tExpectedResult.Text = getSettings.ExpectedResult;
        lMaxExecTimeGetter.Text = tMaxExecTime.Text = getSettings.MaxExecTime;
        lMaxDelayGetter.Text = tMaxDelay.Text = getSettings.MaxDelay;
        lTimeoutGetter.Text = tTimeout.Text = getSettings.Timeout;
    }
```

Do you have any idea ?
I do not understand where is the problem. It is very odd that it happens during a simple Controls.Add()

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to the Viewstate.
I resolve it with :

- in CreateChildControls : all controls are added with visible property
  to false
- I create a function. It tests the edit mode and changes visible
  property according with it

I know it is not a real and very good solution, but it works.
If anyone has better, I am taker !